# What is the nature of implication?

Tags: syllogism

Or: how do statements follow from other statements?

Consider:

All turtles have shells (s1), Ricardo is a turtle (s2), therefore Ricardo has a shell (s3).

Why does s3 follow?

Comment: Common sense logic is either: a) learned through observation during early childhood; b) inborn feature of humans (and some other species). Or both are true within some bounds.